# Assign Credentials (user name/password) to EF in Code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have my entity model and connection set up, and as you probably know when you set up the connection to be stored in the config file, it recommends you don't store the "sensitive" data (i.e. user name and password) in the config file, well what I wanted to do was allow the user to enter that information themselves.

How do I assign it to the connection in code?

Do I have to pull the string, modify it (by adding the user/pass) and then reassign the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sounds like a desktop (not a web app), correct? since you are probably not running over the internet but rather in a local network why don't you use integrated (windows) security instead of the sql server security and hot have to store the login/password at all.

Comment: It just hadn't occurred to me. Sounds like a good bet. I'll give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: integrated security is the preferred authentication method in intranet scenarios. (now I sound like a consultant)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // Add a constructor that takes a connection string
    public MyContext(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {         
    }
}

// Call this method from a page or controller
public void ConnectToTheDatabase(string username, string password)
{
    // create the connection string; I like to user the builder
    System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder builder 
        = new System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder();

    builder.Add("Server", "tcp:asdfewsdfgwe.database.windows.net,1422");
    builder.Add("Database", "supersonic_db");
    builder.Add("User ID", username);
    builder.Add("Password", password);
    builder.Add("Trusted_Connection", "False");
    builder.Add("Encrypt", "True");
    builder.Add("Connection Timeout", "30");

    var connString = builder.ToString();

    // Set the connection string
    MyContext context = new MyContext(connString);

    // Test with something simple
    context.Database.Connection.Open();
    string version = context.Database.Connection.ServerVersion;
    version = version.ToUpper();
}
```